# Errors with bcp and bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

I am having a `.dat` file which I have to upload on my SQL Server 2012 database. The table is as follows:

```
Primary Key TAB_KEY(bigint, not null)
SESSION_KEY (varchar(32),null)
HIT_KEY(varchar(32),null)
NAME(nvarchar(256),null)
VALUE(nvarchar(1024),null)
SESSION_TIMESTAMP(datetime,null)
```

The data file is like this in the `.dat` file:

NOTE : When attempting to import  below these datas via BCP I get an error

> Column 3: String data, right truncation

BTW Column 3 is NAME column in the column.

Sample data for Column 3 (Name Column field) :

```
     _2__Kart_Ücreti_Yans_t_l_rken_180_Gün_Aktiflik_Kontrolü_Yap_lmal_d_r__Kart_ücreti_yans_rken__kart_n_en_son_hangi_tarihte_al__veri__nakit_çekim_veya__Axess_kartlarda__chip_para_harcamas__yap_ld____kontrol_edilecektir__E_er_günün_tarihi_ve_bu_son_aktiflik_t
```

Format file :

```
9.0
5
1       SQLCHAR       0       32      "\t"     2     SESSION_KEY                RAW
2       SQLCHAR       0       32      "\t"     3     HIT_KEY                    RAW
3       SQLCHAR       0       512     "\t"     4     NAME                       RAW
4       SQLCHAR       0       1024    "\t"     5     VALUE                      RAW
5       SQLCHAR       0       24      "\r\n"   6     SESSION_TIMESTAMP          ""
```

Error message :

> Starting copy...  SQLState = 22001, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]String data, right truncation SQLState = 22001,

My BCP command is :

```
bcp TLWEB.dbo.TLWEB_URLFIELD_8X in BulkUrlField8x.20141209_000000_20141209_235959.cxconnect_2_1418121388.1418121852_10032_1.dat -F 2 -b 250000 -m 50 -a 32000 -U username -P xxxxx -S ServerName\InstanceName,Port_Number -f UrlField8x.fmt
```

Comment: The `NAME` is defined as **512** characters in the format file, but only **256** characters in the SQL Server table ....

Comment: hey marc_s like you said I've defined correctly it once again but still issue thanks

Comment: Any comment related to the topic?